# Scheme skip or continue during lambda map

Tags: scheme, racket

I am building a function that takes a set of integers, and returns a subset of the odd integers. I am running into the problem that I need to skip over the even integers in my map, but right now my function returns `#<void>` instead.

```
 (define (oddSubset set)
   (map
     (lambda (x)
       (cond 
         ((odd? x) x)))
     s))
```

In use:

```
> (oddSubset '(1 2 3))
'(1 #<void> 3)
```

Is there logic I can use like "else, continue onto next element"?

Note: I am trying to rewrite the built in filter function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` does not have the possibility to skip, but you can use `filter` instead:

```
(filter odd? '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ; ==> (1 3 5)
```

Or you can use `fold-right`

```
(fold-right (lambda (e acc)
              (if (odd? e)
                  (cons e acc)
                  acc))
            '()
            '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ; ==> (1 3 5)
```

I assume `#!r6rs`. Both `fold-right` and `filter` are in the library `(rnrs lists (6))`. There is also [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#FoldUnfoldMap) which gives both of these procedures for a R5RS language.

In the none standard language `#!racket` uses the name `foldr` in place of `fold-right`.

Answer (score 2):

`map` looks like a weird choice for this. By definition it maps a function onto each element in a list and returns the list of the results, so trying to "skip" elements seems unnatural.

`filter` is what you're looking for.

```
(filter odd? '(1 2 3))
'(1 3)
```

Comment: I am trying to rewrite the built in filter for this.

Comment: Take a look at folding as shown by the answer below mine. If you want to write everything yourself, write a simple function that adds (car input) to the result if it satisfies the condition and then recurses on (cdr input). Any tutorial discussing lisp should have a simple example that you can follow.

Answer (score 1):

`map` applies a function on all elements. Each invocation of the function is supposed to be independant from the others. Even if you introduce a state with a closure, you can't avoid `map` to build a list of same size as your input.
You want to (re-)implement the [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) function. If you want to do it by yourself, you should try to use `foldl` and `foldr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
(cond 
   ((odd? x) x))
```

`map` check each element in the list: if it is odd, then return that element. But you did not tell your program what to do when the element is not odd, so `map` return  `void`.

To solve your problem: use `filter` instead, since `map` will return something for each element in the list.

If you want to know how to implement `filter`, try reading the second chapter of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.3)